# phpinfo() uses old version. What am I missing after "make install"?

Tags: php, module, apache2, debian

I have just built and installed (`./configure`, `make`, `make install`) the actual php version 5.6.9 (from http://php.net/downloads.php) on my Debian squeeze.

Typing `php --version` in the console brings PHP `5.6.9`, as expected.

Now I want to use this version in (a newly restarted) apache2 and to test I use

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

The website shows PHP 5.3.3.

What am I missing? Where do I have to connect apache2 to php and how? Which module or library I have to replace? Where?

Comment: Was 5.3.3 version installed earlier?

Comment: Sure, I wanted to upgrade from PHP 5.3.3 to PHP 5.6.9. I have seen, that apache still uses an old /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so. The new creation of PHP 5.6.9 did not create such a library. `php5` is still installed in `/usr/bin/php5` while the new version `php` lies in `/usr/local/bin/php`. How do I _train_ apache2 to use the new version?

Comment: Provide please command history(how you compiled, where you got sources, etc..)

Comment: I have just added the download-source-link. I followed the INSTALL documentation: `./configure --enable-so` then `make` then at least `make install`. I don't think it is a php problem, becaues `/usr/local/bin/php` works perfectly now, but apache still uses `/usr/bin/php5`.

Comment: I guess you just compiled cli version of PHP, so you need to compile using this manual http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

Comment: I have seen this documentation thanks Sergey Chizhik, but I think I don't have to recompile apache, because apache is already in one of the newest versions. Another question about this documentation is the fact, that there is no `/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs` on my system. Is it possible to use php 5.6.9, without recompiling apache2 (actually 2.2.16 is running)?

Comment: Probably yes. `apxs` - is part of `apache2-dev` package

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I probably posed too many questions so far: What do you mean with "probably yes"? _Probably yes_, it is possible to use without recompiling? Or _probably yes_, I do have to recompile apache?

Comment: Its ok:) I mean that you don't have to recompile, because you can install `apache2-dev` package and get required `apxs`.

Comment: Thanks Sergey Chizhik. I just have installed "apache2-dev". The problem remains. There is no insallation cadidate for apxs (?). Is there any documentation around? Do I have to compile php again? I am still missing something.

Comment: SOLED: Many thanks again Sergey. I had first to install the apache2-dev package. Then, the whole php had to be requilt: 1. find asxp 2. configure (using asxp and mysql) 3. make clean 4. make test (optional?) 5. make install. Now it works!! Great and thanks again and again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it usig the tipps from sergey (see remarks above)

1. install apache2-dev
2. locate apxs (which was on /usr/bin/apxs2)
3. change to the php source package:
4. configure --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2 --with-mysql
5. make clean (! VERY IMPORTANT: Otherwise it won't compile!)
6. make
7. make test
8. make install

works now!

Two addidional notes for joomla users
a) configure --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2 --with-mysql --with-zlib
  (uses zlib)
b) change "mysqli" to "mysql" in the old joomla/configuration.php files.

Comment: Great. Congratulations!

Comment: I forgot configure ... --with-mcrypt (It works, as it stands above, but I get an error running phpmyadmin, when I have no mcrypt installed)